# Why is my amount rounding?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have the following code for distributing money. The dollar bills are always right, it always ends being the change witch gives me the wrong about. I tried `setprecision()` and `ceil` but it only worked for some amounts. I cannot figure out how to fix this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    double amount;
    int twenty, five, one, half_dollar, quarter, dime, nickel, penny; 

    cout <<"Please enter amount: ";
    cin >> amount;
    cout <<"You will need ";

    if (amount >= 20)
    {
        twenty = (amount/20);
        amount = (amount-(20*twenty));
        if (twenty > 0)
        {
            cout << twenty << " $20 bill(s). ";
        }        
    }

    if (amount >= 5 )
    {
        five = (amount/5);
        amount = (amount-(5*five));
        if (five > 0)
        {
            cout << five << " $5 bill(s). ";
        }    
    }

    if (amount >= 1 )
    {
        one = (amount/1);
        amount = (amount-(1*one));
        if (one > 0)
        {
            cout << one << " $1 bill(s). ";
        }        
    }

    if (amount >= 0.50)
    {        
        half_dollar = (amount/0.50);
        amount = (amount-(0.50*half_dollar));
        if (half_dollar > 0)
        {
            cout << half_dollar << " 50c coin(s). ";
        }        
    }

    if (amount >= 0.25 )
    {       
        quarter = (amount/0.25);
        amount = (amount-(0.25*quarter));
        if (quarter > 0)
        { 
            cout << quarter << " 25c coin(s). ";
        }
    }

    if (amount >= 0.10 )
    {                    
        dime = (amount/0.10);
        amount = (amount-(0.10*dime));
        if (dime > 0)
        {
            cout << dime << " 10c coin(s). ";
        }
    }

    if (amount >= 0.05 )
    {      
        nickel = (amount/0.05);
        amount = (amount-(0.05*nickel));
        if (nickel > 0)
        {
            cout << nickel << " 5c coin(s). ";
        }
    }

    if (amount >= 0.01)
    {                     
        penny = (amount/0.01);             
        amount = (amount-(0.01*penny));        
        if (penny > 0)
        {
            cout << penny << " 1c coin(s).\n";
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never, ever, ever, ever, store money (or anything requiring precise counting) as a `float` or a `double`. `int` or `long` is the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of numerical stability and the limitations of Floating Point representations (especially a 32bit ``float`` rather than a 64bit `double`). For a fun example, `0.1` doesn't actually exist as a number in either ``float`` or ``double``, meaning any calculation you do with it will likely not come out as you expect.

Comment: Avoid floating point in monetary calculations, you might use integers, instead

Comment: Use long double and pray :D to be serious, you will need a decimal or at least a fixed-point type. Use long long and  consider the last 4 digits as fractions (then you must do some magic with multiplicative ops)

Comment: Here's a nice example of a proper [Money Pattern implementation](http://www.di-mare.com/adolfo/p/money.htm).

Comment: Looks like your program don't want you to be rich

Comment: @DigitalBrain any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When outputting the number of half dollars, you are actually writing the value for "one"

```
if (half_dollar > 0){
    cout << one << " 50c coin(s). ";
```

which may or may not have been assigned a value.

Comment: thanks, i just corrected that. I am still getting values off by a penny or 25 cents

Comment: At some point, you'll need to compare using something other than just >. For example, if the amount entered is 0.01, the code will get to the last comparison `amount > 0.01` and since 0.01 is not greater than 0.01, the conditional code won't run.

This is also why everyone is recommending not to use floating point types for currency calculations. If it must be done, a common method is to compare the absolute difference of the two numbers with a tolerance - 
`if (abs(amount - 0.01) < 0.0001) {` instead of 
`if (amount > 0.01) {`